# Shp2pgsql encoding issue / error. Special latin /utf characters (áéíóú) are wrong

Tags: postgis, error, encoding

I am not able to load accented vowels coming from a Shapefile, to a PostGis geodatabase.

This is my information:
Operative System: **Windows 10**.
PostgreSql Database: **postgresql-10.5-2-windows-x64.exe**.
Database encoding:  **UTF8**.
Database collation: English United States **1252**.
Database character type: English United States **1252**.
Sql client in Windows: **psql**.
Windows CMD default code page: **437**.
Tool to create SQL from Shapefile: **shp2pgsl**.

1) Commands that I have ran to create the Sql:

```
shp2pgsql -s 21892 -c -g geom -D -k -i -I -W "UTF-8" municipios2.shp public.municipios2 > mun1.sql

shp2pgsql -s 21892 -c -g geom -D -k -i -I -W "LATIN1" municipios2.shp public.municipios2 > mun2.sql
```

On top of mun1.sql and mun2.sql (first line) reads:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO UTF8;
```

2) This is the encoding that Notepad++ shows for those sql files:

```
UCS-2 LE BOM
```

3) In Notepadd ++, next sample words, are inside those sql files:

***CI├ëNAGA***  (must be CIÉNAGA)
***UNI├ôN*** (must be UNIÓN)

4) I tried in Notepad ++ to open those sql files with a different encoding or convert to a different encoding (UTF-8) but it does nothing or shows worst results:

***CI├â┬ëNAGA*** (must be CIÉNAGA).
***UNI├â┬ôN*** (must be UNIÓN)

5) This is the procedure that I did to load some of those files inside Postgis
- In windows command prompt (before use shp2psql of psql) I changed the code page:

```
chcp 1252
```

Inside psql, before load, I changed the client encoding to one of those options:

```
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET client_encoding = 'LATIN1';
```

I load (with psql) those files to the geodatabase:

```
\i 'D:/mun1.sql'
```

with this error
ERROR:  ***invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff***
psql end.

Note: If I convert those sql files to UTF8, they will load to PostGis, but with wrong words (CI├â┬ëNAGA, UNI├â┬ôN)

Of course if I have tested "**Postgis 2.0 Shapefile Loader**", and it works very well with UTF8. But I need shp2psql to use bath load of many shapefiles with specific sql sentence to load.

What should I do to solve the problem?

I have **ogr2ogr** option (I have not work with that), but I have been using shp2psql and I want to know what is the problem.

Comment: +1 good (first?) question info body. seems pedantic, but, as per the rules, only one actual and distinct question per post is allowed on this board...could you rephrase? an equally good answer to this should naturally include info on your different sub-questions I think. btw., it is also discouraged to leave 'thanks' and include your name...seems uncharming at times, but keeps the focus on the issue.

Comment: please re-read my comment. it's a friendly one! I *acknowledged* your very good question! I refered to me citing the rules as pedantic, not to you!

Comment: I am so sorry. The meaning of pendantic is different to the similar word in Spanish - pedante. I apologize you.

Comment: Did you check that the collation you are using exists? There are several ideas here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/49446727/7788694

Answer (score 1):

Probably your shapefile is neither in LATIN1 or UTF8 but in something like `cp1252`. An easy way to check this is open the shapefile in a software like QGIS, open the attribute table and check if there are encoding issues. Then check the the "source" tab in the properties of the shapefile and check the "data source encoding" value.

If there are encoding issues just change the "data source encoding" and open the table again until finally you find the correct encoding.

You can do something similar open directly the .dbf file with LibreOffice Calc.

Then use the shapefile encoding for the `-W` parameter

```
shp2pgsql -s 21892 -c -g geom -D -k -i -I -W cp1252 municipios2.shp public.municipios2 > mun2.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues even using that -W directive. Instead i found that some utility present in the Application Stack Builder helps with this process and inserts directly the records in database. I'm talking about "PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager", an utility that allows precisely that: Importing the records from some SQL files, and also configure the encoding of the records.

[image: PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager]

After hitting the application we should configure

- the encoding:

[image: Encoding window from PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager]

- The db connection:

[image: DB Connection config. in PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager]

- And the SHP file to be imported